# Free SMTP server providers

Tags: smtp

Is there a free SMTP server to send unlimited emails per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Gmail :) See *[Configuring other mail clients](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287)*.

Comment: did not work the limit is 21 mails per day